# xaringan: decrease vertical space between input and output?

Tags: css, r, knitr, xaringan, remarkjs

I cannot figure out how to change the CSS in the xaringan package if I want to decrease the vertical space between code input and output boxes. here is the simple change inside the default xaringan template:

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
institute: "RStudio, Inc."
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Sharingan_triple.svg)

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

???

Image credit: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sharingan_triple.svg)

---
class: center, middle

# xaringan

### /ʃaː.'riŋ.ɡan/

---
class: inverse, center, middle

# Get Started

---

---

# R code

```{r}
1+1
````

I would like to shrink the space between in put and output:

[image]

Here is what I see in my safari course explorer. I guess i just want to shrink the orange area. `pre`? I tried changing that, but messed up the CSS. thanks for any hints.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change css code locally in the file by inserting html `<style></style>` tags. The part that controls the default size of the `pre` elements for xaringan is defined as follows:

```
pre {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

(at least that is the default code I see if I use the [default markdown xaringan template from RStudio](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/xaringan/resources/default.css)).

It is the `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` elements that you need to change. Thus if you add the following right after the yaml in your `.Rmd` file then you should be able to modify the relevant parts.

```
<style>
pre {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0px;
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: awesome! thanks! this works almost perfectly for me. one slight issue is that the first slide (i.e. where I put the `style` tags) does no longer work (i.e. the one with the background-image thing). I had to put the `style` thing on a first, totally empty slide. is there a better solution available? Also, I presume I could place that into a separate `.css` file, right?

Comment: yes works great with the seperate css file. thanks so much!